# Unload event in Windows Form Application in VC ++ 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm designing a program By Visual Studio 2010 in Windows Form Application and I want to have a function that run when my form is closed. How can I add it's proper event handler?

i want an event handler like this:

this->Resize += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Main::Main_Resize);

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Closing` or `Closed` event in your form class, you can call your function in it.

example (C#):

```
Form1 f;
f.Closing += new FormClosingEventHandler(f_Closing);
```

and your function:

```
private void f_closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your function
}
```

Comment: i want a event handler adder like this: this->Resize += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Main::Main_Resize);

Comment: I posted a C# example code, but you'll easily find the C++ equivalent